# C++ *Diagonal Difference* Problem, Where Am I Going Wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm still a beginner to C++ and trying to solve a "diagonal difference" problem.

Given a square matrix, I'm supposed to calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

ex:

```
11 2 4
4 5 6
10 8 -12
```

Primary Diagonal:

```
11
   5
     -12
```

Secondary Diagonal:

```
     4
   5
10
```

**Solution would be 15. (absolute value)**

My code works in some of the test-cases, but not all of them. I am stuck and wondering where I went wrong. Here is what I have so far:

```
int diagonalDifference(vector<vector<int>> arr) 
{
    int firstTotal = 0;
    int secondTotal = 0;
    int absTotal = 0; 
    int firstMiddleNumbers = 0;
    int secondMiddleNumbers = 0;
    int lastY = arr.size()-1;
    int lastX = arr[0].size()-1;

    for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        firstMiddleNumbers += arr[i][i];
    }

    firstTotal = arr[0][0] + firstMiddleNumbers + arr[lastX][lastY];

    for(int j = arr[0].size()-1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        secondMiddleNumbers += arr[j][j]; 
    }

    secondTotal = arr[lastX][0] + secondMiddleNumbers + arr[0][lastY];

    absTotal = abs(firstTotal-secondTotal);

    return absTotal;

}
```

**EDIT:**

Updated solution, still working on putting it into one for loop.

```
int diagonalDifference(vector<vector<int>> arr) 
{
    int firstMiddleNumbers = 0;
    int secondMiddleNumbers = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.size()-1; i++)
    {
        firstMiddleNumbers += arr[i][i];
    }
    for(int j = arr[0].size()-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        secondMiddleNumbers += arr[j][k]; 
        k++;
    }
    return abs(firstMiddleNumbers-secondMiddleNumbers);
}
```

Comment: There's no recursion here, and it's not clear what purpose recursion has here, in the first place. Ignoring recursion, the correct solution would involve only a single `for` loop, and just two variables, and not seven. Two sums, initialized to 0, a single loop, adding the appropriate value to the two sums. Finally, subtracting the two sums and taking the absolute value -- don't you think this is really much, much simpler than all of this complexity?

Comment: Your code is not using recursion to solve the problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik One of the test cases involves a 2D vector with over 500 elements , so it needs to be dynamic, i mis-spoke about recursion I will delete that.

Comment: @boyanhristov96 Yes, sorry. I did not mean to type that, I've edited it out.

Comment: @Tman *One of the test cases involves a 2D vector with over 500 elements* -- And using recursion could blow out the call stack with large data sets.  Iterative, simple solutions are preferred over recursive ones if the data set is large.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have edited out the recursive part, did not mean to write that.

Comment: Ok, so pretty much everything I wrote, in my first comment, holds true.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Only a single sum is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single running "difference total" variable, and only need one for loop.

Hint: visit each column once. You only need one for loop because it is a square matrix. The naive doubly nested for loop (indexes `i` and `j`) approach can be implicitly collapsed into one loop where `column = i`, `rowA = i` and `rowB= (n - 1) - i` (zero based). This is because you can reorder the terms of the additions and subtractions of the expression because integer addition is commutative.

In simpler words, based on your example:

`(11 + 5 - 12) - (10 + 5 + 4)` is the same as `(11 - 10) + (5 - 5) + (-12 - 4)` and you can exploit this fact to simplify your code to visit each column once, accumulate the difference in a single variable instead of trying to evaluate both diagonals and store the intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I got it working using two for loops and edited the question above with my solution, going to try using just one for loop now.

Comment: That's great! your solution seems fine for correctness, doing it minimally with one loop is for bonus points :D

Comment: There is probably one corner case you should handle, which is to handle when you get an invalid zero-size matrix (size is 0), so that you do not have an invalid array access

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `int i` with `unsigned long arr.size()`. Store `arr.size()` in another `int` variable, like `int n = arr.size();` and then use it.